# XAML Binding Value from other Collection

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding

**I really search the internet and could not find a answer.**

*Its hard for me to describe what i try to do. Maybe that is the reason i
could not find a answer on Stackoverflow and Google.*

I have a `ListBox` in my Page which is bound to a `ObservableCollection<Model>`.
This `Model` has a property with a `Id` of another model. There is also 
a `Dictionary<int,SecondModel>` containing the realted second models.

I could **not** add a property with the second model to the first model because this is a third party library.

**Is it possible to get the `Name` property from the realated `SecondModel` using the collection?**

```
Text="{Binding ???}"
```

#### Sample

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SecondModelId { get; set; }
}

public class SecondModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SomeOtherModel
{
    public Dictionary<int,SecondModel> SecondModelCollection{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It s confusing alright :) But you say _ListBox in my Page which is bound to a ObservableCollection<Model>_ then you ask _Is it possible to get the Model from the collection?_ Cos as is, u _are_ using the `Model`

Comment: ;) I mean i want to get the SecondModel but i only have the id. Thanks in advance!

Comment: so using the `ObservableCollection<Model>` as the datasource, you want to get `Name` for example. Did i get it right?

Comment: yes right, i have the `ObservableCollection<Model>`. `Model` has the id of the `SecondModel`... i need the `Name` property of the  `SecondModel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot play with the guts of `Model` class, I ll suggest wrapping the two models in a something like:

```
public class JoinedModel
{
  public Model FirstModel{ get; set; }
  public Model SecondModel{ get; set; }
}

 var secondModelCollection = SomeOtherModel.SecondModelCollection.Values;

 var joinedCollection = from model in firstModelCollection
                              join secondModel in secondModelCollection 
                              on model.SecondModelId equals secondModel.Id
                              select new JoinedModel() { FirstModel = model, SecondModel = secondModel };
```

You can set the joinedCollection as the data source instead of the *firstModelCollection* which isgiven as `ObservableCollection<Model>` in the question.

Then in the binding, you can do a *two level binding* like `Text="{Binding SecondModel.Name}"`

... tho, I am assuming you can change the datasource of your view, I hope you can :)

Answer (score 1):

I like zortkun's solution. You can also use an IValueConverter

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <my:SecondValueConverter x:Name="SecondValueLookup" />
</UserControl.Resources>
  :
  :
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SecondValueId, 
                  Converter={StaticResource SecondValueLookup}, 
                  ConverterParameter=Name}" />
```